# Microsoft graph login not working in android

Tags: android, microsoft-graph-api, android-volley, microsoft-graph-sdks

We are using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` for Microsoft login in the Android app.

but got `com.android.volley.AuthFailureError` error.

**AUTH CONFIG FILE:**

```
{
  "client_id": "...",
  "authorization_user_agent": "DEFAULT",
  "redirect_uri": "msauth://....",
  "account_mode" : "MULTIPLE",
  "broker_redirect_uri_registered": false,
  "authorities" : [
    {
      "type": "AAD",
      "authority_url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
   MSGraphRequestWrapper.callGraphAPIUsingVolley(
                this,
                accessToken,
                "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me",
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        /* Successfully called graph, process data and send to UI */

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                        //Here got error com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
                    }
                });
```

Although it's working with our other clientid, only creates problem in production clientid.

**ERROR:**

```
com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException(NetworkUtility.java:189)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:145)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:132)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
```

```
Volley: [343742] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 403 for
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

I tried to find the answer for this but did not get any reliable answer.

Can anyone please suggest why it's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have correct scope to call garph Api , learn more about the error for 403 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/resolve-auth-errors , we highly recommend you to user MSAL library to to get authenticate and get access token for ghaph API.- https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android .
Create a new MultipleAccountPublicClientApplication instance.
String[] scopes = {"User.Read"};
IMultipleAccountPublicClientApplication mMultipleAccountApp = null;
IAccount mFirstAccount = null;

```
PublicClientApplication.createMultipleAccountPublicClientApplication(getContext(),
    R.raw.msal_config,
    new IPublicClientApplication.IMultipleAccountApplicationCreatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCreated(IMultipleAccountPublicClientApplication application) {
            mMultipleAccountApp = application;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(MsalException exception) {
            //Log Exception Here
        }
    });
Acquire a token interactively
mMultipleAccountApp.acquireToken(this, SCOPES, getAuthInteractiveCallback());

private AuthenticationCallback getAuthInteractiveCallback() {
    return new AuthenticationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(IAuthenticationResult authenticationResult) {
            /* Successfully got a token, use it to call a protected resource */
            String accessToken = authenticationResult.getAccessToken();
            // Record account used to acquire token
            mFirstAccount = authenticationResult.getAccount();
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(MsalException exception) {
            if (exception instanceof MsalClientException) {
                //And exception from the client (MSAL)
            } else if (exception instanceof MsalServiceException) {
                //An exception from the server
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            /* User canceled the authentication */
        }
    };
}
Acquire a token silently
/*
    Before getting a token silently for the account used to previously acquire a token interactively, we recommend that you verify that the account is still present in the local cache or on the device in case of brokered auth

    Let's use the synchronous methods here which can only be invoked from a Worker thread
*/

//On a worker thread
IAccount account = mMultipleAccountApp.getAccount(mFirstAccount.getId());

if(account != null){
    //Now that we know the account is still present in the local cache or not the device (broker authentication)

    //Request token silently
    String[] newScopes = {"Calendars.Read"};
    
    String authority = mMultipleAccountApp.getConfiguration().getDefaultAuthority().getAuthorityURL().toString();

    //Use default authority to request token from pass null
    IAuthenticationResult result = mMultipleAccountApp.acquireTokenSilent(newScopes, account, authority);
}
```

Comment: Good to hear that it works , To access https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me , you should have "User. Read" Permission , as i mentioned in my first line to check scopes , the weird thing in you development client id its already there , you can cross verify by checking the scope by decoding the token.

Comment: It's something weird things happen. now production client id is also working without adding that scope. Maybe some other reason affected.

Comment: I request you to decode and check the access token for production client id  , and share us with , then we will be able to figure out ? Thanks

Comment: Can you please give me any suggestion how can I decode token?

Comment: By using graph explorer- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer and call endpoint - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me , you will see access token , copy that and decode in http://jwt.io/ .

Comment: Yeah, the main cause is related to that scope. Initially, I ran the app by adding that scope, so it added `User.Read` permission to that specific account. 
And after that, it works even without scope also because it already assigned that permission to that account.

Comment: Good to hear that , Thanks for the update , have a good day.